# What is the white vapor seen immediately prior to and during the early part of the launch?

Tags: rockets, launch

As most modern rockets rest on the pad much white vapor is seen.

Is this propellant being vented or condensation from the surrounding air due to the extreme cold of the rocket body?

Comment: Everyone likes pictures. Just sayin'

Comment: Rats. I searched for questions similar and couldn't find. Thanks!